# python mysqldb unable to insert a long string filled with quotes

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to do this

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO my_stats VALUES (%s,%s)""" % (time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), info["countries"]))
```

where info["countries'] is a json string like this
{"US" : 8997, "BG" : 78 ....}

I keep getting syntax error exception from MySQL

I am using Python-MysqlDB

Comment: Please post the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra double-quote at the start of the query string.
Also, you should be passing your parameters as a second argument to `execute` to avoid SQL injection attacks; and to ensure that the values are properly quoted, e.g.:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO my_stats 
                  VALUES (%s, %s);""", (time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 
                                        info["countries"],))
```

If you post the error you're getting we'll be able to help more.

Comment: SQL injection is not a concern in my case, I am not doing anything that requires loading userland variables. both you and cha0site are suggesting this so I am trying this now.

Comment: Understood. Nonetheless this way should be used to hand off quoting duties to the MySQLdb library.

Comment: I got new problem , pls see my response below to cha0site.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the multiline string syntax here? You only have the one line. Anyway, you have an extra `"` in the beginning. But you might as well do this properly and use a prepared statement, it's not like it's any harder, you just replace the `%` with a comma.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO my_stats VALUES (%s,%s)", (time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), info["countries"], ))
```

Comment: sorry the extra " was just a typo in my post. I did not know there was prepared like statement, it did strike me as odd initially. I am not used to using this interface. I will give your method a try now. thanks.

Comment: @Vangel: So it's probably the `"` in the JSON string that's making MySQL barf. Anyway, just use a prepared statement, it'll take care of the quoting for you.

Comment: Now Iget problem in another query where I am inserting integers with %d, it complains TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str. I have even tried int(variable) to no avail.

Comment: @Vangel: Prepared statements are not format strings. You always use `%s`.

Comment: oh damn >.< that was dumbass. I gave answer to Adam only cause he replied first. :) But +1 to you for waking me up. Gotta stop coding for the day.